# GPUImage Framework (GPUImageStillCamera) implementation for iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, opengl-es, gpuimage

i have used GPUImage framework, while run example code for [SimplePhotoFilter](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/tree/master/examples/SimplePhotoFilter) (i have used GPUImageSketchFilter) in iPad am getting some dots over the filtered image, like this:

[image]

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Actually i don't want dots over the filtered image, its working fine in iPhone.

Comment: Which iPad is this, and which iOS version? Is this the front-facing or rear-facing camera? Have you changed any of the code for the SimplePhotoFilter? There is a known bug in the OpenGL ES driver that causes this under certain conditions, so I need to know what to check.

Comment: @BradLarson Am using IOS version 5.1, and i have used rear-facing camera. i didn't change any code from SimplePhotoFilter. it's working fine in iPhone but in iPad am getting this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to a known bug in the iOS 5.x texture caches, and I filed a bug report on it a while ago. Usually, it only strikes when using something other than the AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto preset with an AVCaptureStillImageOutput, but it appears that this can also occur on that preset in certain conditions.

Given the NDA, I can't say whether this has been fixed in iOS 6.0, but try running this with the beta and see for yourself.

As a workaround for iOS 5.x, you can edit the `+supportsFastTextureUpload` method in GPUImageOpenGLESContext to always return NO. This will disable the texture cache support in the framework, but may lead to slower image processing and greater memory consumption when taking photos.